# How can I put the column values as column headers in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table that looks like this:

```
date          name     grade
2021-02-01   John       7.5
2021-02-01   Martha     8.6
2021-02-01   Peter      5.5
2021-02-02   John       8.0
2021-02-03   John       7.0
2021-02-04   Peter      4.0
2021-02-04   Martha     9.1
2021-02-04   Paul       6.3
2021-02-05   John       7.1
2021-02-05   Mary       1.5
2021-02-06   John       3.3
2021-02-07   Martha     1.8
```

I would like to create a new table, but that has as columns the names of each person that column names has.

Like this:

```
date          John     Martha     Peter     Paul     Mary
2021-02-01     7.5      8.6        5.5      null     null
2021-02-02     8.0      null       null     null     null
2021-02-03     7.0      null       null     null     null
2021-02-04     null     9.1        4.0      6.3      null
2021-02-05     7.1      null       null     null     1.5
2021-02-06     3.3      null       null     null     null
2021-02-07     null     1.8        null     null     null
```

What I have tried is this:

```
select date,
case when name = 'John' then grade end as John,
case when name = 'Martha' then grade end as Martha,
case when name = 'Peter' then grade end as Peter,
case when name = 'Paul' then grade end as Paul,
case when name = 'Mary' then grade end as Mary
from mytable
order by date
```

But what I get is:

```
    date          John     Martha     Peter     Paul     Mary
    2021-02-01    7.5       null      null      null     null
    2021-02-01    null      8.6       null      null     null
    2021-02-01    null      null      5.5       null     null
    2021-02-02    8.0       null      null      null     null
    2021-02-03    7.0       null      null      null     null
    2021-02-04    null      null      4.0       null     null
    2021-02-04    null      9.1       null      null     null
    2021-02-04    null      null      null      6.3      null
    2021-02-05    7.1       null      null      null     null
    2021-02-05    null      null      null      null     1.5
    2021-02-06    3.3       null      null      null     null
    2021-02-07    null      1.8       null      null     null
```

Comment: You were basically looking for pivoting the table.

Comment: do you really have just 5 names in your table?!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant No. Around 35.

Comment: no doubt! i asked not really to get the answer  - I thought my question will tell you something :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant oh! Seems I did not catched. Now I'm curious to know what it is. Forgive me for my poor experience with the topics. The reason I have the table that way is because there are around 35 different names, but lots of rows (67M, for example). So that way, I can partition by date and cluster by name. That way the queries are more efficient, right?

Comment: ok. no. this is not what I wanted to point you to. I will follow this later in a day when time allow. "see" you then :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select date,
       max(case when name = 'John' then grade end) as John,
       max(case when name = 'Martha' then grade end) as Martha,
       max(case when name = 'Peter' then grade end) as Peter,
       max(case when name = 'Paul' then grade end) as Paul,
       max(case when name = 'Mary' then grade end) as Mary
from mytable
group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick. Was my approach correct? Or there is other more efficient and elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your approach is fine.

Comment: Thanks. If I would like to forward fill null values? Like something similar to pandas `fillna` method, how the query would change?